# React Table filtering with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-table

I have a component that uses React Table but the filtering is not working for some reason.
When I put a term into the input field, it kind of starts filtering for a ms but nothing happens.
I copied the code from the original examples: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-hugle-nilcb?file=/src/App.js

And only changed the input data, which is coming from my api. It's a long json file, for testing kind of a db mock.
What I really want here is either just one global filter that searches every row or a column filter that accepts inputs and filters out the table.

Thank for your help!

Anyway, my Table Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable, useFilters, useGlobalFilter, useAsyncDebounce } from 'react-table'
// A great library for fuzzy filtering/sorting items
import {matchSorter} from 'match-sorter'
const regeneratorRuntime = require("regenerator-runtime");
const axios = require('axios');

// Material UI imports
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";



const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`

// Define a default UI for filtering
function GlobalFilter({
  preGlobalFilteredRows,
  globalFilter,
  setGlobalFilter,
}) {
  const count = preGlobalFilteredRows.length
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(globalFilter)
  const onChange = useAsyncDebounce(value => {
    setGlobalFilter(value || undefined)
  }, 200)

  return (
    <span>
      {' '}
      <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Keresés" variant="outlined"
              value={value || ""}
              onChange={e => {
                setValue(e.target.value);
                onChange(e.target.value);
              }}
              placeholder={`${count} records...`}
              style={{
                fontSize: '1.1rem',
                border: '0',
              }}
      />
    </span>
  )
}

// Define a default UI for filtering
function DefaultColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, preFilteredRows, setFilter },
}) {
  const count = preFilteredRows.length

  return (
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Keresés" variant="outlined"
    value={filterValue || ''}
    onChange={e => {
      setFilter(e.target.value || undefined) // Set undefined to remove the filter entirely
    }}
    placeholder={`Search ${count} records...`}
    />
  )
}

// This is a custom filter UI for selecting
// a unique option from a list
function SelectColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
  // Calculate the options for filtering
  // using the preFilteredRows
  const options = React.useMemo(() => {
    const options = new Set()
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      options.add(row.values[id])
    })
    return [...options.values()]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  // Render a multi-select box
  return (
    <select
      value={filterValue}
      onChange={e => {
        setFilter(e.target.value || undefined)
      }}
    >
      <option value="">All</option>
      {options.map((option, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}

// This is a custom filter UI that uses a
// slider to set the filter value between a column's
// min and max values
function SliderColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue, setFilter, preFilteredRows, id },
}) {
  // Calculate the min and max
  // using the preFilteredRows

  const [min, max] = React.useMemo(() => {
    let min = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    let max = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      min = Math.min(row.values[id], min)
      max = Math.max(row.values[id], max)
    })
    return [min, max]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={min}
        max={max}
        value={filterValue || min}
        onChange={e => {
          setFilter(parseInt(e.target.value, 10))
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setFilter(undefined)}>Off</button>
    </>
  )
}

// This is a custom UI for our 'between' or number range
// filter. It uses two number boxes and filters rows to
// ones that have values between the two
function NumberRangeColumnFilter({
  column: { filterValue = [], preFilteredRows, setFilter, id },
}) {
  const [min, max] = React.useMemo(() => {
    let min = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    let max = preFilteredRows.length ? preFilteredRows[0].values[id] : 0
    preFilteredRows.forEach(row => {
      min = Math.min(row.values[id], min)
      max = Math.max(row.values[id], max)
    })
    return [min, max]
  }, [id, preFilteredRows])

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
      }}
    >
      <input
        value={filterValue[0] || ''}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          const val = e.target.value
          setFilter((old = []) => [val ? parseInt(val, 10) : undefined, old[1]])
        }}
        placeholder={`Min (${min})`}
        style={{
          width: '70px',
          marginRight: '0.5rem',
        }}
      />
      to
      <input
        value={filterValue[1] || ''}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          const val = e.target.value
          setFilter((old = []) => [old[0], val ? parseInt(val, 10) : undefined])
        }}
        placeholder={`Max (${max})`}
        style={{
          width: '70px',
          marginLeft: '0.5rem',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

function fuzzyTextFilterFn(rows, id, filterValue) {
  return matchSorter(rows, filterValue, { keys: [row => row.values[id]] })
}

// Let the table remove the filter if the string is empty
fuzzyTextFilterFn.autoRemove = val => !val

// Our table component
function InsideTable({ columns, data }) {
  const filterTypes = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Add a new fuzzyTextFilterFn filter type.
      fuzzyText: fuzzyTextFilterFn,
      // Or, override the default text filter to use
      // "startWith"
      text: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
        return rows.filter(row => {
          const rowValue = row.values[id]
          return rowValue !== undefined
            ? String(rowValue)
                .toLowerCase()
                .startsWith(String(filterValue).toLowerCase())
            : true
        })
      },
    }),
    []
  )

  const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      // Let's set up our default Filter UI
      Filter: DefaultColumnFilter,
    }),
    []
  )

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    visibleColumns,
    preGlobalFilteredRows,
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn, // Be sure to pass the defaultColumn option
      filterTypes,
    },
    useFilters, // useFilters!
    useGlobalFilter // useGlobalFilter!
  )

  // We don't want to render all of the rows for this example, so cap
  // it for this use case
const firstPageRows = rows.slice(0, 100)

  return (
    <>
      <Table {...getTableProps()}>
        <TableHead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                  {column.render('Header')}
                  {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
                  <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
          <tr>
            <th
              colSpan={visibleColumns.length}
              style={{
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <GlobalFilter
                preGlobalFilteredRows={preGlobalFilteredRows}
                globalFilter={state.globalFilter}
                setGlobalFilter={setGlobalFilter}
              />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </TableHead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {firstPageRows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      <br />
      <div>Showing the first 20 results of {rows.length} rows</div>
    </>
  )
}

// Define a custom filter filter function!
function filterGreaterThan(rows, id, filterValue) {
  return rows.filter(row => {
    const rowValue = row.values[id]
    return rowValue >= filterValue
  })
}

// This is an autoRemove method on the filter function that
// when given the new filter value and returns true, the filter
// will be automatically removed. Normally this is just an undefined
// check, but here, we want to remove the filter if it's not a number
filterGreaterThan.autoRemove = val => typeof val !== 'number'

function FilteredReactTable() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Partner Adatok',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Igénylés azonosítója',
            accessor: 'logisticsid',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Partner',
            accessor: 'logistics_store',
            // Use our custom `fuzzyText` filter on this column
            filter: 'fuzzyText',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Partner neve',
            accessor: 'age',
            Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
            filter: 'equals',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Város',
            accessor: 'visits',
            Filter: NumberRangeColumnFilter,
            filter: 'between',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Igénylés Időpontja',
            accessor: 'logistics_date',
            Filter: SelectColumnFilter,
            filter: 'includes',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
            Filter: SliderColumnFilter,
            filter: filterGreaterThan,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/Logisztika')
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(data => setData(data[2].data))
    }, [data])
    
  /* const data = React.useMemo(() => data, []) */
  return (
    <Styles>
      <InsideTable columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default FilteredReactTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table was acting this way beacause of the second array argument of the useEffect hook.